# how to write syntax for key value fair symfony console

Tags: symfony, console, command, magento2

I want to update inventory based on sku.
For example

```
php magento update_inventory --sku&quantity=array(1001,10) --sku&quantity=array(1002,20) --sku&quantity=array(1003,30)
```

But I’m not getting how to add options/arguments ?
here user at least need to provide one pair (sku& quantity).
for this i think i have to use ArrayInput class/InputArgument/InputOption.

Can you give some solution or reference to above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at how [`Magento\Setup\Console\Command\AdminUserCreateCommand`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/AdminUserCreateCommand.php) uses options?  Take a look at how that code uses `getOptionsList` in the `configure` method.  For your use case you may want to look into using `InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY`

A good reference will be http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#using-command-options

You may also want to consider a different input format.  For example using arguments instead of options and specifying the format in documentation.

```
php magento update_inventory 1001:10 1002:20 1003:30
```

Comment: i think i have to use delimiter like ' | '. 1001|10 1002|20

Comment: My testing showed that `:` worked fine.  Why do you think you need to use `|`?  I think the only restriction is a space since that is used as a delimiter.

Comment: yes its also fine.may be sku contain ":" . i'm trying to get cleaner solution.